I want to use R to determine whether two data sets match based on their IDS
I want to compare the data between these two files in
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
by the ID
If they match by unique ID in both of the Data frames then Yes should be printed if not then No should be printed


If they match by unique ID in both of the Data frames then Yes should be printed if not then No should be printed

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Simple question, simple answer....use a join

DATA1$match = ifelse(DATA1$ID %in% DATA2$ID, "Yes", "No")

I have used this code so far

match_result <- ifelse(all(df1$ID %in% df2$ID) & all(df2$ID %in% df1$ID), "Yes", "No")

if they match dataset by unique ids and there is even 1 matching data, it shows yes, not no, right

Am I making more sense, how do I post data thats not in images

MrFlick started with a link that suggests dput(), data.frame(), and read.table() as preferable options. There's also [mcve], though less filled-out.

There is also room for interpretation on what you're looking for, tbh. I wonder what you're going to do with this "Yes"/"No" response. Are you hoping to merge these together? Are you planning on filtering one based on the absence of its ID in the other? Are you needing to compare the values as well, or just the presence of ID?

Basically both data sets have the same unique IDS ,the data in the other columns should be the same based on the unique ID. Id they dont match then the output is no , if they do match then the output if yes even if one unique ID is in one but not the other

In the data that I shared the output should be yes even tho one Unique ID isnt in the other

Still not entirely clear -- do you want "df1 is subset of df2" or "df1 and df2 are both subsets of df0"? The latter implying that either one can include unique IDs not included in the other, but the shared IDs must at least be identical?

The answer:
matching_ids<-intersect(X2025$`1`,X2026$`1`)
match_result <- ifelse(length(matching_ids) > 0, "Yes", "No")
print(match_result)


Your question is very open to interpretation, but I gather what you're looking for is a comparison between two data.frames where the requirements for an output of TRUE are

Any data.frame may have IDs not present in the other data.frame
For any ID that is present in both data.frames, values in all other columns must be equal

If this is correct, you could construct a function like:
congruent <- function(df1, df2) {
  df1 <- semi_join(df1,df2,by="ID") %>% arrange(ID)
  df2 <- semi_join(df2,df1,by="ID") %>% arrange(ID)
  isTRUE(all.equal(df1,df2))
}

This first removes all rows from both df's where the ID is not shared. Then checks if the remaining df's have identical contents.
